# Dictionary requires a model item of type IEnumerable

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I'm new to MVC with Linq and in my project, I am getting an error:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Boolean', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Parts.PartsLocation]'.

I am using MVC with EF, so how do I return an IEnumerable?

Here is my Controller:

```
  public async Task<ActionResult> Index(String aContainer)
  {
      var container = from x in db.PartsLocations select x;
      var empty = from y in db.PartsLocations select y;

      if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(aContainer))
      {
          var parent = from a in db.PartsLocations
                       where (a.LocationName == aContainer)
                       select a.ParentLocation;
          return View(await parent.ToListAsync());
      }

      empty = empty.Where(r => r.LocationName.Contains(null));
      return View(await empty.ToListAsync());
  }
```

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<Parts.PartsLocation>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
```

Model:

```
namespace Parts
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class PartsLocation
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public PartsLocation()
    {
        this.ManufacturingParts = new HashSet<ManufacturingPart>();
    }

    public int LocationID { get; set; }
    public int TypeID { get; set; }
    public string LocationName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int PlantID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> BayID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> SecurityGroupID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ParentLocation { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> LastMoved { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }

    public virtual LocationType LocationType { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<ManufacturingPart> ManufacturingParts { get; set; }
    public virtual ManufacturingPlant ManufacturingPlant { get; set; }
}
}
```

Comment: Can you post your model code?

Comment: Sorry, I edited with Model now.

Comment: Is this happening in a scenario where the passed in string is null/empty? This should be returning List<PartsLocation> which would satisfy the IEnumerable. The one thing that stands out is empty = empty.Where(r => r.LocationName.Contains(null));  This looks like it should be empty = empty.Where(r=> null == r.LocationName);

Comment: It returns an empty View when page loads. Then a string is passed in and I am wanting it to return an integer type (ParentLocation) of a record set where the passed in string matches the column LocationName. It seems like it is something with the Linq in where clause.

Comment: @Steve Py - This happens when I pass in a valid string type. If it's a null an empty View will be returned.

Comment: Hi if your view requires the entire model itself , then you can do like below:var parent = from a in db.PartsLocations
                       where (a.LocationName == aContainer)
                       select a; //changed here
          return View(await parent.ToListAsync());

Comment: Perhaps it is an issue with case? You could try either `where (a.LocationName.ToLower() == aContainer.ToLower())` or `(a => String.Equals(a.LocationName, aContainer, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));`

Comment: @KeyurPATEL This did not fix the issue, thanks though.

Comment: @KarthikElumalai I have tried your suggestion and it perhaps it has given more clues to the issue. When I try your suggestion it does not return the entire record set, only the String types, it does not return any integers.

Comment: Your code doesn't show anything that returns a boolean. Are you sure that your action method and the view match?

Answer (score -1):

aContainer Not Null then You have return select

```
      a.ParentLocation
      else PartsLocation List
```

The view model Return Is Difference so Verify The return value

Comment: Hi, I don't know what "The Tow Return is Difference so Verify The return value" means. Could you please explain?